# How can I remove package from Flutter/Dart?

Tags: android, flutter, plugins

I have installed a package in a Flutter project, in Android Studio, and I want to remove it.
How can I do that?

I didn't try anything because I'm a beginner and I don't know what to do.

Comment: It might be helpful to know what plugin it is, and how you installed it

Comment: Is an audio player plugin from pub.dev

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 5):

You probably added the package by writing

```
flutter pub add package_name
```

To remove it simply write

```
flutter pub remove package_name
```

Or alternatively edit the pubspec.yaml file manually by removing the line that references the package.

Comment: I didn't install the plugin from there but from pub.dev.......

Comment: @ViorelPicior-Dragulescu okay, you weren't very clear about that. Technically those are not called plugins. Those are packages. I'll edit this answer in a minute